# How to make one thing open then another

Tags: command-line

So I made a command in ~.bashrc using the command `alias tunes='...'`. So what I want this command to do is have one music video open then once that video is over open up the next video in line. The command I am using is:

```
alias tunes='cd /path/; xdg-open musicvideo.wav; xdg-open musicvideo2.wav;...; cd'
```

and so forth. What it is doing is only opening the last music video then it finishes. I have tried to change out the `;` with `&&` and it gives me the same result. Any help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: A side note: `cd` goes to the user's home directory. `cd -` (with a hyphen) goes to the previous directory as it was right before the previous `cd` command.

Comment: Yes I want it to go back to my home directory after it has finished

Comment: With MP3s, some players only accept one file at a time, throwing away previous MP3s when you start another. Does running, without an alias, `xdg-open musicvideo.wav; xdg-open musicvideo2.wav` have the same issue?

Comment: It doesn't have the same issue it plays one, then the next just as I want it to

Comment: Which media player are you using? Many support play lists either through play list files and/or multiple command-line arguments. It would be far easier and more elegant to use that feature instead of this kludge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `xdg-open` opens immediately and doesn't wait, consider using actual name of music player you use  ( default for Ubuntu would be `totem`) instead of `xdg-open`

Alternatively, what also can be done is this:

```
xdg-open file.wav ; while pgrep -f "file.wav" >/dev/null ; do : ; sleep 1 ; done
```

This probably would be better in a script instead of alias, so you would have multiple lines. Basically, here we've put a while loop that blocks us from going to next statement, and we're repeatedly checking if there's a process that has `file.wav` in its command-line. Once there's no process like that, you can go on to next line of `xdg-open`

Comment: I'm not a total expert, but would it be better to have a `sleep 1;` or something in that loop as well, so that the shell script isn't running 100% of the time for what is essentially a background task?

Comment: @DaboRoss  oh, absolutely ! It's proper to add `sleep`    function into a polling loop, it's just that I forgot to add it. `Errare humanum est`, especially when fatigued :)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you’ve already got an answer to your *specific* code, but I’m wondering why you’re not doing this with some kind of playlist? If you’re trying to make this alias applicable to the widest range of environments it’s possible you might run into some programs that can’t interpret a playlist file (e.g. mplayer requires the `-playlist` option), but in most cases it should work.

[M3U format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U), which widely supported, is a simple text file with one file per line, either with full path or just the file name (assumes the file is in the current directory). This means you can create one with a simple command like…

```
ls *.wav > playlist.m3u
```

…then run…

```
[cd to the relevant directory]
xdg-open playlist.m3u
```

…in your alias. If you’re doing this in a known environment though, it’s probably more reliable to launch a specific program that you know supports the format.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using `xdg-open`. The process dies soon after it calls the actual application (vlc, mplayer, etc) and so the next command is run.

You can check how this occurs if you run this script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
xdg-open /path/to/video &
echo "xdg-open PID is $!."
while [ -e /proc/$! ]; do
    echo "$! is alive."
    sleep 1;
done
echo "$! is not alive anymore."
```

You can launch the media player directly, for example:

```
vlc /path/to/first/video && vlc /path/to/second/video
```

Comment: Yep, that can be done, and  for multiple files, that probably would require multiple loops for each file